# Iteratively increase column by percent in other column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like the one below. I want to iteratively increase `val` by `pct_change` for the appropriate `group`. For example, for `group==1`, `var` would first remain 1.2, then be 1.2+0.1*1.2=1.32, then 1.32+0.2*1.32=1.584. How can I do this without a loop?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'var': [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2],
    'group': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
    'pct_change': [0.15, 0.21, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1]
})

df
  group pct_change  var
0   1   0.15        1
1   2   0.21        1
2   1   0.10        1
3   2   0.20        1
4   1   0.20        1
5   2   0.05        1
```

What I want to obtain:

```
  group pct_change  var
0   1   0.15      1.200
1   2   0.21      1.200
2   1   0.10      1.320
3   2   0.20      1.440
4   1   0.20      1.584
5   2   0.05      1.512
```

UPDATE:
The suggested solution by @Wen doesn't produce the correct answer:

```
df.assign(pct_change=(df['pct_change']+df['var'])).groupby(['group'])['pct_change'].apply(lambda x : x.cumprod()/x.iloc[0])
0    1.00000
1    1.00000
2    1.42000
3    1.64000
4    2.53328
5    2.56168
```

Comment: Share your attempt at solving this.

Comment: I don't see how `pct_change` results in `var`?

Comment: So the first `pct_change` for the first value for each group is ignored?

Comment: Yea I didn't get that part. I would have thought that it also should change the value

Comment: Well not only that but `pct_change` isn't actually (apparently being treated as) a percentage, and the final result of `1.32` for `group == 1` is neither the result of `0.15 * 1` or `1.1 * 1.1`, or `1.25 * 1` or `1.25 * 1.1`. I can't make it add up, whatever way I try.

Comment: For `group==1`, `var` is first 1, then 1*0.10+1=1.1, then 1.1*0.2+1.1=1.32. Same idea for `group==2`.

Comment: @GauravBansal so it means that the first value in column 'pct_change' is not taken into account?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC `cumprod`

```
df.assign(pct_change=(df['pct_change']+1)).groupby('group')['pct_change'].apply(lambda x : x.cumprod()/x.iloc[0])
Out[229]: 
0    1.00
1    1.00
2    1.10
3    1.20
4    1.32
5    1.26
Name: pct_change, dtype: float64
```

Comment: In this process, it doesn't seem to actually multiply `pct_change` with `var`. If I put in a non-one value for `var`, I don't get the correct answer.

Comment: @GauravBansal since your var is always 1 , then pct_change=(df['pct_change']+df['Var']), change this

Comment: That change doesn't work. I modified the question to make `var` 1.2 instead of 1 and show the output of your suggestion.

Comment: @GauravBansal where is modified question ? and also , I just given the roughly Idear base on your sample data , you should investigate more by your own , to make it work in the real data set you have been working on .

Comment: Thank you for downvote , what is the problem of my answer ?